# Weird redirection caused by SSL in all browsers

Tags: browser, osx-lion, ssl, redirection

I have 2 websites, mydomain.com and mydomain.co. Here is the comparison of the 2 websites.

```
mydomain.com | production site  | purchased SSL certification from GoDaddy

mydomain.co  | development site | self generated SSL certification
```

The following issues comes up randomly.

1. When I visit **http**://mydomain.co, the content of **http**://mydomain.**com** shows up but the address keeps as **http**://mydomain.**co**.
2. When I try to sign in on https://mydomain.co/login, SSL warning shows. When I approve it, I get redirected to https://mydomain.com/login.
3. After I sign in on mydomain.co and try to upload an image, I get redirected to mydomain.com and it tells me to login to upload. But the image does get uploaded to the place on mydomain.co.

Since mydomain.co does not have a certified SSL, my guess is the browsers are trying to correct the url for me?

This happens on all my browsers(firefox, safari, chrome and opera, all latest version) on Mac OS Lion. When I switch to windows on the same computer and test with all browsers, everything works as expected.

Any idea why this is happening? I do need some help.

Thanks in advance,

Milo